# Glyphicon weird link decoration behavior

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, text-decorations

Can somebody explain me the difference between setting 'text-decoration: none' via css file and via element.style to a link?

DEMOS:
[with icons](http://www.bootply.com/RSvFYz6iHN) |
[with text](http://www.bootply.com/RSvFYz6iHN)

when you hover over the first icon, (in the first example), you see this little line:

[image: ugly link underline]

Comment: This is the same, but better on file to maintain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just a little fix:

```
a, a:hover {
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of specificity: a `style` attribute on the tag beats a `a:hover` CSS rule beats a `a` CSS rule. There are many tutorials on CSS specificity, like [this one on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference when it comes to large complex web sites, and you want to override and change the styling on something that has already been given styling inline in the HTML, using the style="..." attribute.

For instance, something you want shown in one colour on most pages, but in a different colour on one particular page, or when shown a second time on the same page. Lots of plugins use inline styling, and it makes it difficult to customise them easily.

Because styling using HTML's inline style attribute has almost the highest specificity possible (basically meaning the "strongest power", if you like). The only way to override it then is to use !important, which just compounds the problem as this then makes it even more difficult to do any further overriding.

The other major drawback is that inline styling clutters up your HTML making it harder to maintain, edit, and understand - which is the prime reason for CSS stylesheets, to separate the styling from the content.

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is the whitespace in your html. IF you are linking to something with the glyphicon, and IF you have whitespace between containing elements(or I imagine you could use non breaking spaces instead), that's when you'll see that little underscore character.

⬇️ Should work fine and not show the underscore

```
`<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>`
```

⬇️ Will show the underscore on hover

```
`<a href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
</a>`
```